# python two different equality methods; one normal one and one for sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

I have an object that I'd like to be able to make equality comparisons on where it looks at all of the objects data to make that comparison.  I'd also like to sort the objects based on only one of the object's properties.

Here's an example:

```
@total_ordering
class Msg():
    def __init__(self, value="", timestamp=None):
        self.value = value
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def is_equal(self, other):
        """ 2 messages are equal if they contain all the same values """
        return (
            self.value == other.value
            and self.timestamp == other.timestamp
        )

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp == other.timestamp

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.timestamp < other.timestamp
```

So, with this example I can easily do `sorted(msgs)` and get back an ordered list.  However, because I'm using the `__eq__` to deal with the sorting, I can't do a simple `msg1 == msg2` comparison when I want to test if all of the properties are the same.  If I change the `__eq__` to deal with the equality case, though, will my sort continue to function properly?  In that case it's possible that `not msg1 < msg2` and `not msg1 > msg2` and `msg1 != msg2`... will that not confuse the sort method?

I guess I can use the "key" argument on `sorted`, but as I have only one way I'd like to sort these objects I'd like to incorporate an automatic way for it to sort them properly.

It'd be nice if there was a `__key__` magic operator that `sorted` called.

Comment: Have you tried using the `key` argument to `sorted()`?

Comment: @Kevin - I'm thinking you stopped reading my question some point before the last two paragraphs...

Comment: OK, so why don't you just write a function that calls `sorted()` with the appropriate `key`?  I'd tend to favor [do simple things](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoSimpleThings) here.

Comment: @Kevin - that's fine.  I just want to know if there's a way to make `sorted()` always do the "right" thing AND also have an `__eq__` operator that evaluates the way I want.

Comment: Well... [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) says it only uses `<` comparisons.  I would *guess* that `sorted()` makes the same promise.  But you should definitely avoid the situation where `foo == bar and foo < bar`, because that makes no sense anyway.

Comment: I guess I could try that, but then I'd need to drop `total_ordering` and define the rest manually.